# How well does eframe persistence scale vertically

Tags: database, rust, egui

I am writing a Japanese learning application using [egui](https://egui.rs/) and the [Wanikani API](https://docs.api.wanikani.com/20170710/), and am planning to cache (a lot of) data locally - 11 tables and thousands of records in most tables. Will egui's built in persistence (which uses RON and serde) be enough or will it scale too poorly to work with this amount of data?

Comment: Tens of thousands of records doesn't sound like that much honestly, but you've provided no information on what kinds of data you're storing, nor what kind of scaling you're talking about. In terms of memory usage? Or (de-)serializing throughput? These kinds of questions can usually only be answered by benchmarking.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity; the data would be strings, audio files (MPEG and OGG), and images (SVG and PNG), images and audio both typically ~10 kilobytes. I'm concerned about storage space usage, and whether I'd be justified in using an SQL database.